# NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription string added in info.plist is not showing in permission popup ios

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <array>
        <string>Location is required to find out where you are</string>
    </array>
    <key>Privacy-Location Usage Description</key>
    <string>Location is required to find out where you are.</string>
```

I have added this in info.plist. Still the permission popup does not shows the string added,Instead it shows-- 
Allow "app" to access your location even when you are not using the app?

Comment: are your tried in simulator or device

Answer (score 21):

**Use CLLocationManager**

- Add the following line in your Info.plist file (right clic -> Open as -> Source Code)

  ```
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Your explanation</string>
  ```
- Add the CLLocationManagerDelegate to your swift file

  ```
  class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {...}
  ```
- In your viewDidLoad() function, write the following lines :

  ```
  var locationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
  locationManager.delegate = self
  locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
  ```

It should work ! Hope I helped you !

Comment: Hey thanks, got it working . I had to remove <array> tag in info.plist