# QT/Qml PositionSource can not access location because of privileges on OS X

Tags: macos, qt, location, qml, qtpositioning

I need to obtain device current location information with Qt/Qml/Quick and C++ on Mac OS X. I test it:

```
    PositionSource {
        id: src
        updateInterval: 60000
        active: true
        preferredPositioningMethods: PositionSource.AllPositioningMethods


        Component.onCompleted: {
              src.start()
              src.update()
              var supPos  = "Unknown"
              if (src.supportedPositioningMethods == PositionSource.NoPositioningMethods) {
                   supPos = "NoPositioningMethods"
              } else if (src.supportedPositioningMethods == PositionSource.AllPositioningMethods) {
                   supPos = "AllPositioningMethods"
              } else if (src.supportedPositioningMethods == PositionSource.SatellitePositioningMethods) {
                   supPos = "SatellitePositioningMethods"
              } else if (src.supportedPositioningMethods == PositionSource.NonSatellitePositioningMethods) {
                   supPos = "NonSatellitePositioningMethods"
              }
              console.log("Position Source Loaded || Supported: "+supPos+" Valid: "+valid);
        }

        onPositionChanged: {
            var coord = src.position.coordinate;
            console.log("Coordinate:", coord.longitude, coord.latitude);
            backend.longitude = coord.longitude;
            backend.latitude = coord.latitude;
            console.log(src.nmeaSource)
        }
    }
```

When I run it on Qt Creator, I get this this ok/cancel popup : "TestApp" would like to use your current location.". if I click ok button, it can obtain current device location information (latitude, longitude, etc.)

On the other hand, when I try to run app on terminal (path: TestApp.app/Content/MacOs/TestApp) or deploy with "macqdeploy", the popup didn't appear and it can't obtain current location.

For deployment, I also test copying all Qt/Qml/QuickControl libs/frameworks to bundle manually, but it also doesn't work.

I should deploy my application, so location information is necesarry. How can I solve this problem? How can get privileges popup again?

Thanks!

Edit:

This is my Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSUIElement</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>app2.app always location use</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: share your plist file is more important.

Answer (score 0):

You need a property list *`info.plist`* file in your project if you don't have one. I think starting from iOS10 /macOS10 this file controls permissions. Refer to Apple's guide  [About Info.plist Keys and Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html)
for details.

In your case, I think you need this entry in your `info.plist` file:

```
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} always location use</string>
```

the following SO posts might be help:

[Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278220/nslocationalwaysusagedescription-string-added-in-info-plist-is-not-showing-in-pe)

[NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription string added in info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278220/nslocationalwaysusagedescription-string-added-in-info-plist-is-not-showing-in-pe)

Comment: How can I access ${PRODUCT_NAME} ? Is it application name? Here TestApp or TestApp.app? I used all of them but method returns NaN.

Comment: @gkhanacer, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872175/how-do-i-change-the-product-name-within-an-xcode-project